# How do I add a js reference to the body of my page and a css reference to the head of my page?

Tags: javascript, css, head

The only place I have access to edit is: CMS > Pages > 'page' > Content

Can I add a jquery reference to the body of my page like this in the content area?

```
<body>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/image-map-pro.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

And then, how would I add a css reference to the head of my page?

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/image-map-pro.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/squares.min.css">
</head>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I advise not doing it and doing it via code inside your codebase.
but you can still do it here:

go to design tab of your CMS->Layout Update XML

```
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="blockname">
            <action method="setText">
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[link rel="stylesheet" href="css/squares.min.css">/>]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
   <reference name="content">
                 <action method="setText">
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[<script src="js/jquery.min.js" />]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </reference>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll give this a try once I'm given better permissions, it seems I don't have enough to make these changes yet. (I don't see the > Design tab)